# Refresh .bashrc with new env variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, environment-variables

I have a production server running our rails app, and we have ENV variables in there, formatted correctly. They show up in `rails c` but we have an issue getting them to be recognized in the instance of the app.

Running puma, nginx on an ubuntu box.
What needs to be restarted every time we change .bashrc?  This is what we do:
1. Edit .bashrc
2. `. .bashrc`
3. Restart puma
4. Restart nginx

still not recognized..but in rails c, what are we missing?

edit:
Added env variables to `/etc/environment` based on suggestions from other posts saying that `.bashrc` is only for specific shell sessions, and this could have an effect.  supposedly `/etc/environment` is available for all users, so this is mine.  still having the same issues:

1. Show up fine in rails c
2. Show up fine when I echo them in shell
3. Do not show up in application

   ```
   export G_DOMAIN=sandboxbaa3b9cca599ff0.mailgun.org
   export G_EMAIL=mailgun@sandboxbaa3ba3806d5b499ff0.mailgun.org
   export GEL=support@xxxxxx.com
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
   ```

edit:

In the app i request `G_DOMAIN` and `G_EMAIL` in plain html (this works on development with dotenv, does not work once pushed to production server with ubuntu server) :

```
      ENV TEST<BR>
      G_DOMAIN: <%= ENV['G_DOMAIN'] %><br>
      G_EMAIL:<%= ENV['G_EMAIL'] %>
```

However, the following env variables are available to use (in both .bashrc and /etc/environment, same as all variables we displayed above) because our images work fine and upload to s3 with no issue, on production.

production.rb

```
  # Configuration for Amazon S3
  :provider              => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

edit2: could this be anything with this puma issue?

https://github.com/puma/puma/commit/a0ba9f1c8342c9a66c36f39e99aeaabf830b741c

Comment: Have you thought about having the app read from a text file rather than environment variables, for data which is liable to change like this?  It's a lot simpler and more reliable.

Comment: That looks right to me, although I'm not sure you should need to restart `NGINX`.  Are you certain you are updating the environment variables in `.bashrc` for your application?  So, for instance, in my case, I have multiple apps running on the server so I need to log in as the app user, reload `.bashrc` and then restart the app in that same context/folder (`unicorn` in my case, but it should be the same for `puma`, just less mythical :).

Comment: @steveklein we're using the right `.bashrc` because the other `env` vars are being picked up just fine, and are in the same file.  it only has an issue with the newest one we've added

Comment: @MaxWilliams we could do that, but we already have all of our vars in .bashrc working fine, i would rather just figure out what we're doing wrong

Comment: So if you change the value of an "existing" var, it gets picked up in the application, but the new var is not recognized?  Sounds like a typo somewhere... You could update your post with a sanitized snippet from `.bashrc`.

Comment: not a typo @steveklein , we know that the first two are being picked up, the rest are not.  but they ALL get picked up in `rails c`

Comment: Can you update your OP with sanitized .bashrc?

Comment: @steveklein i ended up moving all of these to `/etc/environment` based on suggestions, but still get the same result.  posting that to OP

Comment: wow this sounds pretty frustrating.  So are you able to access `G_DOMAIN` and `G_EMAIL` in your app, but not `GEL`?  Can you add a code/log snippet demonstrating this to your OP?

Answer (score 5):

I was having a problem like this, also. For me, this only happens when I add a new environment variable.

Through [this post](http://railsguides.net/how-to-define-environment-variables-in-rails/) and after some more googling, I've come to understand that the `restart` command for Puma (via the gem `capistrano-puma`) might not see new environment variables because the process forks itself when restarting rather than killing itself and being started again (this is a part of keeping the servers responsive during a deploy).

The linked post suggests using a YAML file that's only stored on your production server (read: NOT in source control) rather than rely on your deploy user's environment variables. This is how you can achieve it:

1. Insert this code in your Rails app's `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

2. Add this code to your Capistrano deploy script (`config/deploy.rb`)

```
  desc "Link shared files"
  task :symlink_config_files do
    on roles(:app) do
      symlinks = {
        "#{shared_path}/config/local_env.yml" => "#{release_path}/config/local_env.yml"
      }
      execute symlinks.map{|from, to| "ln -nfs #{from} #{to}"}.join(" && ")
    end
  end

  before 'deploy:assets:precompile', :symlink_config_files
```

3. Profit! With the code from `1`, your Rails application will load any keys you define in your server's Capistrano directory's `./shared/config/local_env.yml` file into the `ENV` hash, and this will happen before the other config files like `secrets.yml` or `database.yml` are loaded. The code in `2` makes sure that the file in `./shared/config/` on your server is symlinked to `current/config/` (where the code in `1` expects it to be) on every deploy.

Example local_env.yml:

```
SECRET_API_KEY_DONT_TELL: 12345abc6789
OTHER_SECRET_SHH: hello
```

Example `secrets.yml`:

```
production:
  secret_api_key: <%= ENV["SECRET_API_KEY_DONT_TELL"] %>
  other_secret: <%= ENV["OTHER_SECRET_SHH"] %>
```

This will guarantee that your environment variables are found, by not really using environment variables. Seems like a workaround, but basically we're just using the `ENV` object as a convenient global variable.

(the capistrano syntax might be a bit old, but what is here works for me in Rails 5... but I did have to update a couple things from the linked post to get it to work for me & I'm new to using capistrano. Edits welcome)